# How to respond only to our web form

Tags: php, forms, security, jwt, http-referer

This may be a generic question.

I have a web form on my web server at example.com. Data is posted (POST) to a PHP page which returns some data.

But how to prevent my PHP page to respond to any copy of the form hosted anywhere ?

[image: secure form]

I know HTTP_REFERER is a bad idea as it can be changed client side.
I thought about a JSON Web Token (JWT) in a hidden field but it can be scraped from the form page and used in the localhost form.

Is there a secured way for this problem ?

Comment: Based on your idea of JWT, you can use a CRSF token by generating an uniq value for an user

Comment: It's a workaround and doesn't fully solve your problem, but you can create a captcha to prevent automated posts.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Nothing beyond the edge of your webserver is under your control.

Anyone can submit any HTTP request they like, using whatever client they like (including a `telnet` client into which they type raw HTTP commands).

An Anti-CSRF token (which is what you appear to be going for with JWT) can prevent a third party from tricking a logged-in user from submitting a bad request: but that's the best you are going to get.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about [CRSF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) Token - but it can be scrapped by curl and used in any other form. As @Quentin mentioned - it only will get harder to use by others - not secure You at all.

Answer (score 0):

I partially disagree with @quentin's answer.

You can create **unique token** via `php`, save it on server side and pass it to an [obfuscated](https://obfuscator.io) `js` code block. The obfuscated `js` will  then write the token to a `COOKIE` or `local storage` that will be used to match against the server token on form submission, needless to say that clients without `js` enabled  (curl, wget, etc...) won't be able to run this code.
The point of having an obfuscated `js` instead of regular `js` is to prevent clients without `js` to scrap our webpage, steal the unique token and use it to submit the form posing as a valid user, as mentioned on @bigwolks's answer.
Make sure the token in valid only for a **limited amount of time** to prevent reuse.
This setup needs customization to fit each particular project, but it has proven to be a valid defensive measure against automated submissions from non `js` clients on my projects.

---

Obfuscated `js` example:

```js
var _0x3d71=['\x65\x46\x50\x58\x78','\x45\x55\x70\x63\x6f','\x77\x59\x66\x50\x52','\x75\x56\x65\x65\x61','\x64\x65\x62\x75','\x4e\x69\x50\x59\x57','\x74\x6e\x6d\x67\x55','\x64\x78\x4e\x52\x51','\x75\x79\x48\x65\x45','\x4b\x48\x7a\x6e\x4a','\x66\x72\x64\x6d\x47','\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x28\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x28\x29\x20','\x69\x4d\x4b\x75\x72','\x7b\x7d\x2e\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72\x28\x22\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x22\x29\x28\x20\x29','\x77\x64\x4b\x65\x7a','\x67\x54\x7a\x52\x7a','\x52\x75\x6e\x6e\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x61\x6e\x20\x4f\x62\x66\x75\x73\x63\x61\x74\x65\x64\x20\x4a\x61\x76\x61\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x20\x42\x6c\x6f\x63\x6b','\x43\x58\x49\x66\x68','\x43\x4b\x4d\x74\x6b','\x61\x70\x70\x6c\x79','\x41\x65\x55\x44\x67','\x55\x59\x70\x4d\x78','\x51\x6c\x45\x41\x4c','\x72\x6b\x4f\x69\x43','\x59\x54\x78\x66\x54','\x5a\x65\x68\x52\x43','\x47\x51\x4a\x70\x65','\x57\x50\x77\x58\x68','\x74\x43\x5a\x79\x43','\x4e\x75\x45\x78\x55','\x52\x43\x43\x7a\x61','\x74\x65\x73\x74','\x75\x58\x46\x44\x76','\x37\x7c\x34\x7c\x32\x7c\x30\x7c\x31\x7c\x33\x7c\x38\x7c\x36\x7c\x35','\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x6f\x6c\x65','\x73\x70\x6c\x69\x74','\x64\x65\x62\x75\x67','\x77\x61\x72\x6e','\x6c\x6f\x67','\x74\x72\x61\x63\x65','\x64\x56\x6d\x67\x45','\x4e\x74\x72\x45\x62','\x44\x44\x66\x4a\x6f','\x6a\x6c\x5a\x6d\x70','\x72\x56\x43\x75\x63','\x63\x62\x59\x43\x6e','\x4c\x41\x4a\x6e\x68','\x4c\x76\x6f\x6a\x65','\x70\x58\x57\x70\x65','\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72','\x7a\x55\x4b\x64\x70','\x63\x61\x6c\x6c','\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e','\x69\x6e\x66\x6f','\x65\x72\x72\x6f\x72','\x65\x78\x63\x65\x70\x74\x69\x6f\x6e','\x79\x6f\x75\x20\x6d\x61\x64\x65\x20\x69\x74','\x42\x62\x41\x6b\x77','\x66\x4f\x75\x41\x75','\x5c\x2b\x5c\x2b\x20\x2a\x28\x3f\x3a\x5f\x30\x78\x28\x3f\x3a\x5b\x61\x2d\x66\x30\x2d\x39\x5d\x29\x7b\x34\x2c\x36\x7d\x7c\x28\x3f\x3a\x5c\x62\x7c\x5c\x64\x29\x5b\x61\x2d\x7a\x30\x2d\x39\x5d\x7b\x31\x2c\x34\x7d\x28\x3f\x3a\x5c\x62\x7c\x5c\x64\x29\x29','\x6c\x6f\x68\x6b\x72','\x56\x42\x61\x4b\x79','\x75\x65\x42\x45\x5a','\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74','\x53\x65\x71\x61\x74','\x56\x49\x63\x64\x48','\x70\x59\x79\x73\x48','\x72\x73\x4f\x64\x6b','\x63\x73\x45\x71\x63','\x71\x4e\x59\x54\x72','\x52\x4a\x58\x47\x45','\x6b\x45\x48\x78\x43','\x70\x7a\x6c\x6a\x4c','\x6c\x65\x6e\x67\x74\x68','\x62\x5a\x63\x75\x73','\x74\x58\x7a\x4f\x48','\x67\x67\x65\x72','\x73\x72\x66\x73\x43','\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x4f\x62\x6a\x65\x63\x74','\x46\x48\x76\x78\x7a','\x46\x71\x54\x51\x51','\x64\x59\x63\x4f\x65','\x43\x4c\x6a\x4e\x69','\x68\x52\x67\x71\x6f','\x6f\x55\x45\x44\x4c','\x6a\x68\x6d\x57\x75','\x65\x42\x68\x61\x61','\x70\x5a\x49\x55\x62','\x71\x5a\x4a\x55\x6f','\x77\x68\x69\x6c\x65\x20\x28\x74\x72\x75\x65\x29\x20\x7b\x7d','\x63\x6f\x75\x6e\x74\x65\x72','\x50\x69\x6d\x78\x6a','\x53\x6c\x79\x43\x4f','\x4f\x56\x76\x6b\x49','\x70\x6d\x77\x51\x61','\x6b\x63\x63\x56\x42','\x72\x68\x4a\x50\x76','\x41\x4e\x44\x47\x57','\x59\x48\x6e\x56\x64','\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x20\x2a\x5c\x28\x20\x2a\x5c\x29','\x6a\x45\x4a\x66\x77','\x56\x77\x56\x43\x4f','\x71\x53\x50\x6c\x6a','\x69\x6e\x69\x74','\x77\x50\x74\x41\x66','\x44\x54\x4b\x6c\x73','\x63\x68\x61\x69\x6e','\x4c\x68\x58\x6b\x6c','\x52\x63\x74\x70\x53','\x45\x42\x45\x6e\x61','\x57\x4e\x4f\x62\x56','\x55\x50\x72\x47\x77','\x53\x70\x79\x72\x47','\x4d\x43\x76\x68\x62','\x57\x67\x54\x41\x4c','\x46\x4c\x6a\x56\x68'];(function(_0x1ce1e8,_0x11cd39){var _0x5acfc0=function(_0x4c0038){while(--_0x4c0038){_0x1ce1e8['push'](_0x1ce1e8['shift']());}};_0x5acfc0(++_0x11cd39);}(_0x3d71,0x1ba));var _0x40c5=function(_0x1161cb,_0x37896a){_0x1161cb=_0x1161cb-0x0;var _0x1c585d=_0x3d71[_0x1161cb];return _0x1c585d;};function _0x5ca343(){var _0x54e445={};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x0')]=_0x40c5('0x1');_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x2')]=_0x40c5('0x3');_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x4')]=function(_0x5333d8,_0x5b68c2){return _0x5333d8!==_0x5b68c2;};_0x54e445['\x4c\x55\x53\x70\x41']=_0x40c5('0x5');_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x6')]='\x5c\x2b\x5c\x2b\x20\x2a\x28\x3f\x3a\x5f\x30\x78\x28\x3f\x3a\x5b\x61\x2d\x66\x30\x2d\x39\x5d\x29\x7b\x34\x2c\x36\x7d\x7c\x28\x3f\x3a\x5c\x62\x7c\x5c\x64\x29\x5b\x61\x2d\x7a\x30\x2d\x39\x5d\x7b\x31\x2c\x34\x7d\x28\x3f\x3a\x5c\x62\x7c\x5c\x64\x29\x29';_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x7')]=function(_0x3ae9a5,_0x40c6cb){return _0x3ae9a5(_0x40c6cb);};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x8')]=_0x40c5('0x9');_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0xa')]=function(_0x1701f8,_0x489286){return _0x1701f8+_0x489286;};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0xb')]=_0x40c5('0xc');_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0xd')]=function(_0x51bf84,_0x4a96ca){return _0x51bf84+_0x4a96ca;};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0xe')]=_0x40c5('0xf');_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x10')]=function(_0x24dc40,_0x2bc95e){return _0x24dc40(_0x2bc95e);};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x11')]=function(_0x502489,_0x889243){return _0x502489!==_0x889243;};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x12')]='\x6b\x6a\x4a\x50\x5a';_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x13')]=function(_0x25f659,_0x4e1c33,_0xa58c1c){return _0x25f659(_0x4e1c33,_0xa58c1c);};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x14')]=_0x40c5('0x15');_0x54e445['\x6e\x59\x55\x72\x6e']=_0x40c5('0x16');_0x54e445['\x4c\x76\x6f\x6a\x65']=function(_0x27b4b5,_0x2ec56f){return _0x27b4b5!==_0x2ec56f;};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x17')]=function(_0x27084f,_0x3051bd){return _0x27084f(_0x3051bd);};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x18')]=function(_0x3bf408,_0x9bc05){return _0x3bf408+_0x9bc05;};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x19')]=_0x40c5('0x1a');_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x1b')]='\x67\x67\x65\x72';_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x1c')]=function(_0x311eb0,_0x4b8989){return _0x311eb0===_0x4b8989;};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x1d')]='\x49\x55\x7a\x75\x4d';_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x1e')]=_0x40c5('0x1f');_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x20')]=function(_0x2d382d,_0x26f7e5){return _0x2d382d+_0x26f7e5;};_0x54e445['\x4c\x41\x4a\x6e\x68']=_0x40c5('0x21');_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x22')]=_0x40c5('0x23');_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x24')]=function(_0x8fdef5,_0x42cd50,_0x3618f1){return _0x8fdef5(_0x42cd50,_0x3618f1);};_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x25')]=_0x40c5('0x26');var _0xd81104=function(){var _0x46aefb={};_0x46aefb[_0x40c5('0x27')]=_0x54e445.pmwQa;_0x46aefb[_0x40c5('0x28')]=_0x54e445.rhJPv;var _0xadfab6=!![];return function(_0x32970f,_0x4db575){if(_0x46aefb[_0x40c5('0x28')]!==_0x46aefb[_0x40c5('0x28')]){if(_0x4db575){var _0x36bea7=_0x4db575[_0x40c5('0x29')](_0x32970f,arguments);_0x4db575=null;return _0x36bea7;}}else{var _0x30ce84=_0xadfab6?function(){if(_0x4db575){if(_0x46aefb[_0x40c5('0x27')]!==_0x40c5('0x1')){that=window;}else{var _0x42d1d7=_0x4db575[_0x40c5('0x29')](_0x32970f,arguments);_0x4db575=null;return _0x42d1d7;}}}:function(){};_0xadfab6=![];return _0x30ce84;}};}();(function(){var _0x5cdb03={};_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x2a')]=function(_0x3a51d7,_0x20e58c){return _0x54e445.YHnVd(_0x3a51d7,_0x20e58c);};_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x2b')]=_0x40c5('0x2c');_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x2d')]=_0x54e445.LUSpA;_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x2e')]=_0x54e445.jEJfw;_0x5cdb03['\x52\x43\x43\x7a\x61']=function(_0x103b67,_0x1642fb){return _0x54e445.VwVCO(_0x103b67,_0x1642fb);};_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x2f')]=_0x54e445.qSPlj;_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x30')]=function(_0x4c373f,_0x41a918){return _0x54e445.wPtAf(_0x4c373f,_0x41a918);};_0x5cdb03['\x65\x72\x58\x7a\x45']=_0x54e445.DTKls;_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x31')]=function(_0x547ff0,_0x585bca){return _0x54e445.LhXkl(_0x547ff0,_0x585bca);};_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x32')]=_0x54e445.RctpS;_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x33')]=function(_0x2d86ca,_0x3ee448){return _0x54e445.WNObV(_0x2d86ca,_0x3ee448);};if(_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x11')]('\x6b\x6a\x4a\x50\x5a',_0x54e445['\x53\x70\x79\x72\x47'])){if(fn){var _0x516284=fn[_0x40c5('0x29')](context,arguments);fn=null;return _0x516284;}}else{_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x13')](_0xd81104,this,function(){if(_0x5cdb03['\x41\x65\x55\x44\x67'](_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x2b')],_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x2b')])){var _0x3e2209=firstCall?function(){if(fn){var _0x49b7f2=fn[_0x40c5('0x29')](context,arguments);fn=null;return _0x49b7f2;}}:function(){};firstCall=![];return _0x3e2209;}else{var _0x34dbfc=new RegExp(_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x2d')]);var _0x54ce28=new RegExp(_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x2e')],'\x69');var _0x2f754d=_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x34')](_0x577bc3,_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x2f')]);if(!_0x34dbfc[_0x40c5('0x35')](_0x5cdb03[_0x40c5('0x30')](_0x2f754d,_0x5cdb03['\x65\x72\x58\x7a\x45']))||!_0x54ce28['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](_0x5cdb03['\x57\x50\x77\x58\x68'](_0x2f754d,'\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74'))){if(_0x5cdb03['\x74\x43\x5a\x79\x43']!==_0x40c5('0xf')){var _0x2e9330={};_0x2e9330[_0x40c5('0x36')]=_0x40c5('0x37');that[_0x40c5('0x38')]=function(_0x5c010a){var _0x47c9b5=_0x2e9330[_0x40c5('0x36')][_0x40c5('0x39')]('\x7c'),_0x3ea9af=0x0;while(!![]){switch(_0x47c9b5[_0x3ea9af++]){case'\x30':_0x35be71[_0x40c5('0x3a')]=_0x5c010a;continue;case'\x31':_0x35be71['\x69\x6e\x66\x6f']=_0x5c010a;continue;case'\x32':_0x35be71[_0x40c5('0x3b')]=_0x5c010a;continue;case'\x33':_0x35be71['\x65\x72\x72\x6f\x72']=_0x5c010a;continue;case'\x34':_0x35be71[_0x40c5('0x3c')]=_0x5c010a;continue;case'\x35':return _0x35be71;case'\x36':_0x35be71[_0x40c5('0x3d')]=_0x5c010a;continue;case'\x37':var _0x35be71={};continue;case'\x38':_0x35be71['\x65\x78\x63\x65\x70\x74\x69\x6f\x6e']=_0x5c010a;continue;}break;}}(func);}else{_0x5cdb03['\x4e\x75\x45\x78\x55'](_0x2f754d,'\x30');}}else{_0x577bc3();}}})();}}());var _0x34a7ce=function(){var _0x5219ac=!![];return function(_0xa69db9,_0x7fef32){var _0x3caa84={};_0x3caa84[_0x40c5('0x3e')]=function(_0x5cf234,_0x40a8ff){return _0x5cf234!==_0x40a8ff;};_0x3caa84[_0x40c5('0x3f')]=_0x54e445.WgTAL;_0x3caa84['\x44\x44\x66\x4a\x6f']=_0x54e445.nYUrn;var _0x298249=_0x5219ac?function(){if(_0x7fef32){if(_0x3caa84['\x64\x56\x6d\x67\x45'](_0x3caa84['\x4e\x74\x72\x45\x62'],_0x3caa84[_0x40c5('0x40')])){var _0x1ae086=_0x7fef32[_0x40c5('0x29')](_0xa69db9,arguments);_0x7fef32=null;return _0x1ae086;}else{var _0x22fb8b=_0x7fef32['\x61\x70\x70\x6c\x79'](_0xa69db9,arguments);_0x7fef32=null;return _0x22fb8b;}}}:function(){};_0x5219ac=![];return _0x298249;};}();var _0x117072=_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x24')](_0x34a7ce,this,function(){var _0x545a29={};_0x545a29[_0x40c5('0x41')]=function(_0x124ec5,_0x1532f9){return _0x54e445.EUpco(_0x124ec5,_0x1532f9);};_0x545a29['\x7a\x55\x4b\x64\x70']=function(_0x29c03e,_0x23dc12){return _0x54e445.wYfPR(_0x29c03e,_0x23dc12);};_0x545a29[_0x40c5('0x42')]=_0x54e445.uVeea;_0x545a29[_0x40c5('0x43')]=_0x54e445.NiPYW;if(_0x54e445['\x74\x6e\x6d\x67\x55'](_0x54e445['\x64\x78\x4e\x52\x51'],_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x1e')])){_0x545a29[_0x40c5('0x41')](debuggerProtection,0x0);}else{var _0x263cb8=function(){};var _0x3128cd;try{var _0x3fa1c1=_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x17')](Function,_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x20')](_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x20')](_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x44')],_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x22')]),'\x29\x3b'));_0x3128cd=_0x3fa1c1();}catch(_0x4f5054){_0x3128cd=window;}if(!_0x3128cd[_0x40c5('0x38')]){_0x3128cd[_0x40c5('0x38')]=function(_0x742987){if(_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x45')](_0x40c5('0x46'),_0x40c5('0x46'))){(function(){return!![];}[_0x40c5('0x47')](_0x545a29[_0x40c5('0x48')](_0x545a29[_0x40c5('0x42')],_0x545a29[_0x40c5('0x43')]))[_0x40c5('0x49')](_0x40c5('0x4a')));}else{var _0x5f0970={};_0x5f0970[_0x40c5('0x3c')]=_0x742987;_0x5f0970[_0x40c5('0x3b')]=_0x742987;_0x5f0970[_0x40c5('0x3a')]=_0x742987;_0x5f0970[_0x40c5('0x4b')]=_0x742987;_0x5f0970[_0x40c5('0x4c')]=_0x742987;_0x5f0970[_0x40c5('0x4d')]=_0x742987;_0x5f0970[_0x40c5('0x3d')]=_0x742987;return _0x5f0970;}}(_0x263cb8);}else{_0x3128cd['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x6f\x6c\x65']['\x6c\x6f\x67']=_0x263cb8;_0x3128cd[_0x40c5('0x38')][_0x40c5('0x3b')]=_0x263cb8;_0x3128cd[_0x40c5('0x38')]['\x64\x65\x62\x75\x67']=_0x263cb8;_0x3128cd[_0x40c5('0x38')][_0x40c5('0x4b')]=_0x263cb8;_0x3128cd['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x6f\x6c\x65']['\x65\x72\x72\x6f\x72']=_0x263cb8;_0x3128cd[_0x40c5('0x38')]['\x65\x78\x63\x65\x70\x74\x69\x6f\x6e']=_0x263cb8;_0x3128cd[_0x40c5('0x38')][_0x40c5('0x3d')]=_0x263cb8;}}});_0x117072();var _0x34fb91=_0x40c5('0x4e');_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x17')](alert,_0x54e445[_0x40c5('0x25')]);}_0x5ca343();function _0x577bc3(_0x514660){var _0x1b1fd2={};_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x4f')]=function(_0x2a794a,_0x441a05){return _0x2a794a!==_0x441a05;};_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x50')]=_0x40c5('0x51');_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x52')]=function(_0x486481,_0x227078){return _0x486481+_0x227078;};_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x53')]=_0x40c5('0xc');_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x54')]=_0x40c5('0x55');_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x56')]=function(_0x48b4e3,_0x292762){return _0x48b4e3(_0x292762);};_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x57')]=function(_0x557b71){return _0x557b71();};_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x58')]=_0x40c5('0x59');_0x1b1fd2['\x4f\x4a\x6c\x68\x68']=function(_0x2147b8,_0xb36779){return _0x2147b8===_0xb36779;};_0x1b1fd2['\x71\x5a\x4a\x55\x6f']='\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67';_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x5a')]=function(_0x37945d,_0x5c5b0a){return _0x37945d!==_0x5c5b0a;};_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x5b')]='\x6b\x42\x59\x51\x59';_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x5c')]=_0x40c5('0x5d');_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x5e')]=_0x40c5('0x5f');_0x1b1fd2['\x58\x7a\x45\x7a\x7a']=function(_0x646f20,_0x28b461){return _0x646f20%_0x28b461;};_0x1b1fd2['\x53\x6c\x79\x43\x4f']='\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e';_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x60')]=_0x40c5('0x1a');_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x61')]=_0x40c5('0x62');_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x63')]=_0x40c5('0x64');_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x65')]=function(_0x39b5de,_0x43ee72){return _0x39b5de(_0x43ee72);};_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x66')]=_0x40c5('0x67');function _0x191459(_0x30583b){var _0x388f10={};_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x68')]=_0x40c5('0x5');_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x69')]=_0x1b1fd2.fOuAu;_0x388f10['\x50\x69\x6d\x78\x6a']=function(_0x414841,_0x2eca08){return _0x1b1fd2.lohkr(_0x414841,_0x2eca08);};_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x6a')]=_0x1b1fd2.VBaKy;_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x6b')]=_0x1b1fd2.ueBEZ;_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x6c')]=function(_0x36bff4,_0x2cfa4e){return _0x1b1fd2.Seqat(_0x36bff4,_0x2cfa4e);};_0x388f10['\x59\x65\x44\x50\x4b']=function(_0x2e2e84){return _0x1b1fd2.VIcdH(_0x2e2e84);};if(_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x58')]===_0x40c5('0x6d')){return![];}else{if(_0x1b1fd2['\x4f\x4a\x6c\x68\x68'](typeof _0x30583b,_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x6e')])){if(_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x5a')](_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x5b')],_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x5c')])){return function(_0x36937a){}[_0x40c5('0x47')](_0x40c5('0x6f'))[_0x40c5('0x29')](_0x40c5('0x70'));}else{_0xabebd0(this,function(){var _0xe30cd5=new RegExp(_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x68')]);var _0x2ebaad=new RegExp(_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x69')],'\x69');var _0x1f1e74=_0x577bc3('\x69\x6e\x69\x74');if(!_0xe30cd5[_0x40c5('0x35')](_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x71')](_0x1f1e74,_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x6a')]))||!_0x2ebaad[_0x40c5('0x35')](_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x71')](_0x1f1e74,_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x6b')]))){_0x388f10[_0x40c5('0x6c')](_0x1f1e74,'\x30');}else{_0x388f10['\x59\x65\x44\x50\x4b'](_0x577bc3);}})();}}else{if(_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x5a')]((''+_0x30583b/_0x30583b)[_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x5e')]],0x1)||_0x1b1fd2['\x4f\x4a\x6c\x68\x68'](_0x1b1fd2['\x58\x7a\x45\x7a\x7a'](_0x30583b,0x14),0x0)){(function(){return!![];}['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72'](_0x1b1fd2['\x6c\x6f\x68\x6b\x72'](_0x40c5('0x1a'),_0x40c5('0x62')))[_0x40c5('0x49')](_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x72')]));}else{(function(){if(_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x4f')](_0x40c5('0x73'),'\x4f\x56\x76\x6b\x49')){_0x577bc3();}else{return![];}}[_0x40c5('0x47')](_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x52')](_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x60')],_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x61')]))[_0x40c5('0x29')](_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x63')]));}}_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x56')](_0x191459,++_0x30583b);}}try{if(_0x514660){return _0x191459;}else{if(_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x66')]==='\x64\x59\x63\x4f\x65'){_0x191459(0x0);}else{_0x1b1fd2[_0x40c5('0x65')](result,'\x30');}}}catch(_0x2ed0ee){}}
```

---

PS: Not all JavaScript obfuscators are effective. I've found [obfuscator.io](https://obfuscator.io/) to be one of the best due the high number of options, specially the `Domain lock` and  `Debug Protection` options.
According to the creator, It's "*impossible*" to revert the obfuscated code (please read the comments regarding "*impossible*"):

[image]

Comment: Security through obsfucation? Sounds like a bad idea

Comment: @NicoHaase There's not a lot of options in this case and, as of today, you can't un-obfuscate https://obfuscator.io.

Comment: So why use obfuscation after all? If the token is written to a cookie, then it is present on the client

Comment: I don't think that you've fully understood my answer or I didn't explain myself well. **The token is written to a cookie or local storage only  if `js` is enabled.**

Comment: The "no, it's impossible" is simply incorrect. It takes a lot of manual work, but people reverse obfuscation all the time.

Comment: @ceejayoz I agree with you, "*No*" should be replaced with "*as of today*", still, the work of Timofey Kachalov is of great value and very difficult to un-obfuscate. https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator. I do think it suffices to OP's task.

Comment: And what keeps my bot from just evaluating the obfuscated JS code and reading the token from there?

Comment: @NicoHaase Your bot can freely crawl the webpage containing the obfuscated javascript, but it won't be able to do anything with the js code.

Comment: Why do you think that? Why shouldn't my bot be able to do the same stuff a browser can do? There's stuff like https://github.com/nacmartin/phpexecjs - or I let my bot run something like PhantomJS or even a headless Chrome session and voila, there's the cookie.

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm finding hard to understand your comments. Please read my answer carefully. I never mentioned PhantomJS or any other js enabled client. "***Why shouldn't my bot be able to do the same stuff a browser can do***?" Have you tried to un-obfuscate the js code above? I'll delete my answer If you do.

Comment: I don't want to de-obfuscate the code, but run it. I don't care about the un-obfuscated version of the code if there is a way to **execute** it and let it do it's work. And please, even if I disagree with your solution, I think that your answer and our discussion is valuable to the original question - so don't delete it

Comment: You cannot simply "***run it***", as it needs to be located on the same domain as the one previously specified on the obfuscation `Domain Lock` option. I won't delete the answer, as long as you don't unobfuscate the code :-)